# Stylelint WebStorm incorrect showing backlights code

Tags: css, webstorm, lint, stylelint

Incorrect:

[image]

I need it to do this (correct):

[image]

I've tried to reinstall Stylelint, change config file and this not working for me.

In my project we use module css and I'm use this glob `{**/*,*}.{css}` for run. Also I've tried to use this `{**/*,*}.module.{css}` and it doesn't work.